# How do you change the Track template of a Slider?

Tags: wpf, slider

I would want to change the track a slider.  Is there a way to do this?

```
<Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
    <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
        <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"/>
    </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
    <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}"/>
    </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
    <Track.Thumb>
        <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderThumbStyle}"/>
    </Track.Thumb>
```

Answer (score 4):

A track just handles the positioning of the Thumb and the Repeat buttons [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.track.aspx).  The actual look of the track is in the template of the Slider.

To change the look of the "track" change the following area, PART_SelectionRange, in the control template

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Slider}">
<Border SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="{TemplateBinding MinHeight}"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TickBar x:Name="TopTick" Height="4" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Placement="Top"/>
        <TickBar x:Name="BottomTick" Height="4" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="2" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Placement="Bottom"/>
        <Border Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="center" Height="20.0" Grid.Row="1" Background="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderTrackNormalBackground}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderTrackNormalBorder}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="1">
            <Canvas Margin="-6,-1">
                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRange" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1.0" Height="4.0" Visibility="visible"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Border>
        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1">
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="{x:Static Slider.DecreaseLarge}"/>
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource SliderRepeatButtonStyle}" Command="{x:Static Slider.IncreaseLarge}"/>
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb x:Name="Thumb" Style="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderThumbStyle}"/>
            </Track.Thumb>
        </Track>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```